# how to fix flyspell-lazy args-out-of-range error?

Tags: flyspell

I use [flyspell-lazy](https://github.com/rolandwalker/flyspell-lazy) to improve flyspell performance and it works really well. However, when I open a buffer with a lot of text, I get this error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range #<buffer buffer2> 155 215)
  #<subr buffer-substring-no-properties>(215 155)
  ad-Advice-buffer-substring-no-properties(#<subr buffer-substring-no-properties> 215 155)
  apply(ad-Advice-buffer-substring-no-properties #<subr buffer-substring-no-properties> (215 155))
  buffer-substring-no-properties(215 155)
  flyspell-lazy-check-pending()
  apply(flyspell-lazy-check-pending nil)
  timer-event-handler([t 0 3 0 t flyspell-lazy-check-pending nil idle 0])
```

Here's another version of the error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range #<buffer 0-why-I-wrote-this-book.txt> 90378 90651)
  buffer-substring-no-properties(90651 90378)
  flyspell-lazy-check-pending()
  apply(flyspell-lazy-check-pending nil)
  timer-event-handler([t 0 3 0 t flyspell-lazy-check-pending nil idle 0])
```

How can I resolve this error?

As requested, here are my flyspell settings:

```
(use-package flyspell
:config
'(flyspell-abbrev-p t)
'(flyspell-use-global-abbrev-table-p t)
'(global-flyspell-mode t)

:bind
(:map flyspell-mode-map 
("C-." . nil)
)
)

;; flyspell skip source blocks
;; NO spell check for embedded snippets
(defadvice org-mode-flyspell-verify (after org-mode-flyspell-verify-hack activate)
  (let ((rlt ad-return-value)
        (begin-regexp "^[ \t]*#\\+begin_\\(src\\|html\\|latex\\)")
        (end-regexp "^[ \t]*#\\+end_\\(src\\|html\\|latex\\)")
        old-flag
        b e)
    (when ad-return-value
      (save-excursion
        (setq old-flag case-fold-search)
        (setq case-fold-search t)
        (setq b (re-search-backward begin-regexp nil t))
        (if b (setq e (re-search-forward end-regexp nil t)))
        (setq case-fold-search old-flag))
      (if (and b e (< (point) e)) (setq rlt nil)))
    (setq ad-return-value rlt)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (flyspell-lazy-mode 1)))
```

Comment: In general, most forum participants would probably rather help you fix your problem instead of suppressing a meaningful error message.  It's like disconnecting the engine light indicator inside a vehicle rather than going to see a mechanic ... :)

Answer (score 1):

`flyspell-lazy.el` does not apply any `advice` to `buffer-substring-no-properties`.  It will be necessary to find out where else in the user-configuration said function has been advised and undo-it or fix-it.

Comment: Here's another version of the same error: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range #<buffer 0-why-I-wrote-this-book.txt> 90378 90651)
  buffer-substring-no-properties(90651 90378)
  flyspell-lazy-check-pending()
  apply(flyspell-lazy-check-pending nil)
  timer-event-handler([t 0 3 0 t flyspell-lazy-check-pending nil idle 0])`

Comment: You have likely broken `buffer-substring-no-properties` by applying an unknown `advice` at some point in the past -- either you did it yourself, or you installed something from somewhere that did it.  Your problem is not likely with the `flyspell-lazy.el` library.  I cannot see a legitimate reason to ever advise `buffer-substring-no-properties`, but there may be one that you are aware of.  In either case, your `advice` is not correct -- it needs to be fixed or removed, wherever it is.  There is no way to know what you did when creating the `advice` because you have not provided that code.

Comment: To the extent that you are able to locate and remove the `advice` and the problem still persists, please consider updating your question with the relevant settings for both `flyspell` and `flyspell-lazy` so that the forum participants can reproduce your results/issues when loading lengthy files.